# How to scale figures with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created two figures with different data sizes. Therefore, the y-axis of figure 2 is more stretched than the other (figure 1), and as a result, the width of figure two is smaller. 
How do I scale the two figures to an equal size?

[image: Figure 1]

The code I used  for figure 1 is as follows:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%y')
fig=plt.imshow(df, cmap='YlOrBr', interpolation='nearest', 
vmin=0, vmax=12)

l1 = pd.to_datetime(df.index).month
l2 = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).hour
x = pd.Series(l2).drop_duplicates()
y = pd.Series(l1).drop_duplicates()

plt.xticks(x.index,('00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', 
'05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', 
'13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', 
'21:00', '22:00', '23:00'), rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y.index,('', 'Mar `18 ', 'Feb `18', 'Jan `18', 'Dec `17', 
'Nov `17'))
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Time (UTC)")
plt.ylabel("Date")
plt.title("title")
plt.savefig('fig.svg', dpi=1200)
plt.show()
```

[image: Figure 2]

The code I used for figure 2 is as follows:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%y')
fig=plt.imshow(df, cmap='YlOrBr', interpolation='nearest', 
vmin=0, vmax=12)

l11 = pd.to_datetime(df.index).month
l12 = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).hour
x = pd.Series(l12).drop_duplicates()
y = pd.Series(l11).drop_duplicates()

plt.xticks(x.index,('00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', 
'05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', 
'13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', 
'21:00', '22:00', '23:00'), rotation=90)
plt.yticks(y.index,('', 'Oct `18 ', 'Sep `18', 'Aug `18', 'Jul `18', 
'Jun `18', 'May `18', 'Apr `18'))
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Time (UTC)")
plt.ylabel("Date")
plt.title("title")
plt.savefig('df.svg', dpi=1200)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using matplotlib's object-oriented syntax, you can set the figure size when it is initialized:

```
fig = plt.figure(0, figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.subplots(nrow=1, ncols=1)

ax.imshow(df, cmap='YlOrBr', interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=12)
```

The name of some of the commands are slightly different in object-oriented syntax.  `plt.xticks` becomes `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_xticklabels`.  `plt.xlabel` becomes `ax.set_xlabel`